# ajax not work when click open in new window after right click in django template

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i created a link with ajax this is a html coded:

```
<a id="post_click"  href="{{ post.online_url}}" rel="nofollow">
 <button class="w-100 "  type="button" name="button">
    <span class="">link</span>
</button>
</a>
```

and this is ajax :

```
$(function () {
$('#post_click').on('click', function () {
    var Status = $(this).val();
    var id = {{post.id}}
    $.ajax({
        url: "/post-click/" + id,
        data: {
       
        },
        dataType : 'json'
    });
});
```

});

if i push left click ajax work fine in sever side, but when i push left right click and choose open in new window ajax doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the good url in href for doing that :

```
<a id="post_click" href="/post-click/{{post.id}}" rel="nofollow">
 link
</a>
```

Comment: thanks but there is two url here, first url  is : href="{{ post.online_url}}"  , this url refere to another website , and ajax url is  url: "/post-click/" + id, that refer to inside server and does somthing else , In other words, two requests are sent to 2 URLs with one click

Comment: the **right click -> new tab** use the href so if you want to trigger the same action as ajax request, you have to set the same url. you have not described the behaviour you are waiting so i supposed it is that : if you wan to another behaviour, you have to explain it
The right click -> new tab is a your browser behaviour, you cannot define a specific case with js to catch it.

Comment: whats your suggestion for this case

Comment: it exists js lib for logging user behaviour. But i repeat : you do not give any details for explaining what you want really do ?

Comment: If you just want to prevent user to access to the page without ajax calling, you can remove url in the href et make the redirect action in the success function of the ajax call

Comment: Strange, what is unclear to you now, I clearly explained that I want a request to be sent to two URLs by clicking on one link. The first URL is related to another site and the second URL is an internal URL specified by Ajax

Comment: i clearly respond for two url click point. You have not explained what is the finality of your code ? I wrote two idea for responding for your problem according to your purpose : log user action ? Prevent open link without logging ? ... If the finality is different, you have to tell us

Comment: with first url i want to open another url , but with ajax url i want to log user action and recorde it in database as a number +

Comment: You have to use a view in your django. User-click will go to another website by passing in your view. you log the action and redirect it. If user use right-click -> new window action, the new page open on your django view before redirecting it and you can log it too

Comment: yes , i think this will work , thanks